# How do I initialize angular2 materialize component?

Tags: typescript, angular, materialize

I just started using angular2 materialize and the CSS components work fine. However when I include a component that needs initialization (such as select) I have no idea how or where to do that.

This is a snippet of my form:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

My component looks something like this:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MaterializeDirective} from "angular2-materialize";

declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'bsi-signup',
    styleUrls: ['assets/styles/app.component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'assets/templates/signup.component.html',
    directives: [MaterializeDirective],
    providers: []
})

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
    elementRef: ElementRef;

    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
}

    ngOnInit() {
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('select:not([multiple])').material_select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add the attribute `materialize="material_select"`

```
<select materialize="material_select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<label>Materialize Select</label>
```

> The MaterializeDirective attribute directive (materialize) accepts any MaterializeCSS initialization call to apply to the element. The list of supported functions are provided by MaterializeCSS. Examples: collapsible, leanModal, tooltip, dropdown, tabs, material_select, sideNav, etc.

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize

Comment: @ muetzerich Yeah thanks, I actually noticed myself the second I posted the question (typical). :P

Answer (score 1):

**Hi every one !!! this works form me:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var Materialize:any; //we declarate the var Materialize for use 

@Component({
  //your code
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( ) {
    //your code
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // your code
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(){ // Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views.
    Materialize.updateTextFields();// update de fields when the document and the views a are ready
                                   // in case that the inputs are empty 
  }

  updateInformation(){
     // your code ...
     Materialize.updateTextFields(); // update the fields, 
                                     // is not necesary add the class="active" in the views
  }



}
```

Comment: Yes because you need other angular files , this is only a configuration example in your component, you can post your code for help you

Comment: Yup worked! Btw I noticed that your native language is Spanish due to your name and the "update DE fields" instead of "the". Jajaja Gracias!